# Генерация случайных связных графов

Tags: графы

Нужно написать генератор так, чтобы на выходе получалась матрица смежности. Проблема в том, что граф, который будет задан матрицей смежности, должен быть связанным. Как мне наиболее логично организовать функцию связки? Алгоритмов видел достаточно, но они , в основном, генерируют графы под какую-то конкретную цель. Мне же нужно только то, чтобы он был связным.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тривиальное решение

Писать обычный генератор случайных связей. Затем вычислить число различных групп (пометить, к какой группе относится та или иная вершина), добавить хотя бы одну связь между любыми вершинами двух различных групп, объединить группу в одну, и затем повторить, пока существуют различные группы.

Не берусь утверждать, что оно самое быстрое, но зато самое понятное. Да и случайность присутствует, которая вам так нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Функция принимает на вход матрицу смежности в виде двумерного массива однобайтовых целых чисел и количество вершин.
Далее мы идем форами по нему. У нас, как я понимаю, простой граф, и из вершин не исходят петли. Поэтому вершина сама себе не смежна.
Если индексы i и j совпадают, то мы зануляем этот элемент.Присваиваем случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 1 элементу с индексом
[ i ][ j ] (1- смежность вершин i и j). Если i смежна j, то присваиваем элементу [ j ][ i ] тоже единицу, так как если i смежна j, то и j смежна i.

```
void get_rand_edges(uint8_t** matrix, int vertex_num)
{
    for(int i=0; i< vertex_num;i++)
        for(int j=0;j< vertex_num;j++)
        {
            if(i== j)
                matrix[i][j]= 0;
            else
            {
                matrix[i][j]= rand()%2;
                if(matrix[i][j])
                matrix[j][i]=1;
            }
        }
}
```

для получения разных результатов при нескольких запусках программы используйте:

```
srand(time(NULL));
```

Оно привязывает rand ко времени компьютера.

Comment: Вопросу семь полных лет. Вашу решение даже на двух вершинах будет в половине случаев давать несвязный граф. Иногда даже граф не получится. :(